# Tricky ruby class init---- why same class initialize output differently?

Tags: ruby, class

look this class:

```
class Test
  def initialize a, b, c
    @a = a, @b = b, @c = c
  end
  end

class AnotherTest
  def initialize a, b, c
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end
end

array = []

array.push Test.new "a1" ,"b1", "c1"
array.push AnotherTest.new "a2" ,"b2", "c2"

p array
```

I think this should be the same,but not:

```
<Test:0x000000022aba78 @b="b1", @c="c1", @a=["a1", "b1", "c1"]>
<AnotherTest:0x000000022ab9b0 @a="a2", @b="b2", @c="c2">]
```

Anybody who can give me an explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try in irb this expression:

```
a = "something" #=> "something"
```

As you can see, the assignment operation returns the result, because in ruby every expression should return something. So then this expression:

```
@b = b #=> b
```

will return the value of `@b`. Then in this expression

```
@a = a, @b = b, @c = c
```

where `@b = b` and `@c = c` will evaluate to `b` and `c`

So finally we will have this expression:

```
@a = a, b, c
```

And as you know it's another form for initialization of array

```
@a = [a, b, c]
```

This code will work equivalently to yours:

```
class Test
  def initialize a, b, c
    @a = a, b, c
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end
end
```

Addition:
The order of evaluating is significant.
If you try this expression:

```
@a = a, (@b = b, @c = c)
```

Firstly, it will evaluate everything in parentheses:

```
@b = b, @c = c #=> @b = [b,c] and @c = c
```

So then we'll get this

```
@a = [a,[b,c]]
@b = [b,c]
@c = c
```

Comment: But that doesn't explain why @b didn't evaluate to [b, @c]. You would think it would go right to left.

Answer (score 3):

Parallel assignment looks like this:

```
@a, @b, @c = a, b, c
```

Not just in ruby, it looks like that in every language that does parallel assignment.

Answer (score 2):

`@a` is being initialized with an array of values.  You could write `a = 1, 2, 3` and `a` will be assigned with the list `[1, 2, 3]`.  Hence `@a` in your example is being assigned as a list of three values `'a1'`, `'b1'` and `'c1'`.

To break it up, it is seen as `@a` = `a, @b = b, @c = c`.

What you might have wanted is simply:

```
class Test       
  def initialize a, b, c       
    @a = a; @b = b; @c = c       
  end       
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Comma in assignment statement treated specially in Ruby. Thus above result.

```
 @a = a, @b = b, @c = c
```

In above expression, Ruby sees first = as part of an assignment statement. Ruby sees values in right hand side of equal (rvalues) as comma separated values, thus, evaluate each of comma separated values first. This cause @b and @c to get assigned, each of these expression return the assigned values also.

Then, since @a is the only item in left hand side of the assignment statement, rvalues are treated as an array, and the array is assigned into @a. Values are consists of a, b and c. This is what happened.

So, if you want three assignments to happen, then, separating assignments by semicolon
to make all of them statements make Ruby happy.

Note that, You can state multiple items in left hand side of the = too.